# Java, Hibernate - Runtime exception occured when running an existing project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

The following exception is coming when I am trying to run an existing project. Any pointer will be very helpful.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/app_config/applicationContext-dao.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.j
ava:965)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactor
y.java:898)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java
:485)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:4
56)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:24
8)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:100)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.Hibern
ateTransactionManager]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:74)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:958)                                                                                                                  48535,34      97%
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getCachedFactory(LogFactory.java:979)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getFactory(LogFactory.java:435)                                          48536,34      97%
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
                                                                                                                          48573,27-34   97%
```

below is how the bean is defined

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: The error seems to be that it cannot create a `Log` or something from using apache commons logging.

Comment: I am not very sure as I can also see this line - "Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException" . Is it because of log. If yes, then how can I fix this.

Comment: Check the bottom of your stacktrace: *Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getCachedFactory(LogFactory.java:979)*.

Comment: Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Nope from what you show. It is very strange that Apache Commons Logging fail. Looks like you have some specific configuration in your project that you're not showing in the post that's causing this problem.

Comment: apache commons logging version ?

Comment: I just looked at the code for `org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory` (for version 1.1.1, as this is used by Spring). Line 979 is `factory = (LogFactory) factories.get(contextClassLoader);`, so the field `factories` must be `null` to produce this exception. And indeed: I cannot see, where this field is ever initialized. Strange!

Comment: Now I'm starting to think that you haven't added the necessary libraries for your project (which makes me wonder how it compiled to begin with...)

Comment: using commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, commons-logging-adapters-1.1.1.jar and commons-logging-api-1.1.1.jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory.html#getFactory()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory.html#getFactory%28%29)

See the link. It requires a `commons-logging.properties` do you have any file like that in classpath?

Comment: nope. can you please give a example what should be there in this file ?

Comment: I have log4j.properties in my classpath.

Comment: I think this is not the problem. The `getFactory` method starts with determining the context class loader and then runs line 435 which is `LogFactory factory = getCachedFactory(contextClassLoader);`. Now see my comment under the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

İt can't find bean class and return nullpointerexception .

Check all class and package names are true and check your app'sname.hbm.xml file is true named . You have to put class name which you run in app'sname area ..

And check you mapped your app'sname.hbm.xml file into hibernate.cfg.xml file

Comment: It finds the bean, but inside the bean there is a `null` variable being used.

Comment: Maybe some column names different from database or not exist in database

Comment: No. The error comes from Apache Commons Logging. Read the stacktrace again.